# How do I turn a motor using a digital pin in the setup() function?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to turn a motor on using an Arduino board. The motor is not working, but if I plug the motor in to the GND and 5V pins, it turns. How can I fix this? My code is

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
}

void loop() {


}
```

Update: I tried using pin 13, and the LED did not turn on. The motor is sputtering though. This could be a hardware problem.

Comment: If you had read and understood the datasheets of both your motor and your Arduino part, this question would never have arisen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware, electronics, and not reading the documentation for elements of a system.

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic - my reasoning being that this is an issue easily encountered when doing software-hardware interfacing. OP mistakenly believed the issue was with his code, and someone else might think the same in the future. Therefore, I think it's fair to say this is software-related, even if the solution was a hardware issue. Moreover, just see the [official definition here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This post is clearly under "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct to think this is hardware related! Your code to *activate* the motor is fine. However...

Arduino digital pins do not have the ability to **power** a motor. ***Don't damage your board by attempting it further***. See [this post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=225511.0).

In short summary (in the interest of inevitably dead links):

> You need to understand the difference between a signal line and a power line.
>
> Signal lines use voltage(s) and/or current(s) to carry information (analog of digital), but
>   operate usually at very low power levels (less is better for signals, since its waste power).
>
> A power line carries power.
>
> Never confuse the two.

The digital signal pins have a very low current output. Enough to power an LED, but not a motor. Use a transistor between the digital output and a separate power supply to power your motors.

*Aside*: anyone who knows anything about circuitry feel free to correct me: I only have a basic knowledge in that area

Comment: The [Properties of Pins Configured as OUTPUT](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) chapter basically agrees with you.  "_... not enough current to run **most** relays, solenoids, or motors_"

Comment: Yes.  Unless the motor runs on 20mA.  OP should READ THE DATASHEET.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for finding the literature on that. And yes, **always** read the datasheet! Also, from the link: "*attempting to run high current devices from them, can damage or destroy the output transistors in the pin, or damage the entire Atmega chip*"... OP may have already damaged his pins - hopefully he hasn't attempted it on any others!

Comment: I was re-purposing a motor from a school project that didn't come with the data sheet. I now plan on making a makeshift relay out of a servo to power the motor through a battery

Comment: @Nailuj29 Understandable. Generally the datasheets can be searched for and found online with a parts number. Your solution should work just fine providing the relay does not require anything over 40mA. There will also be a substantial delay when using the relay instead of a transistor, somewhere around 50ms. Just FYI

Comment: I'm using an SG90, so I should be fine